# Using One Slicer to Control Monthly and YTD Counts

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

I want to be able to use a single slicer to see the monthly and YTD counts of my categories.

Example:
When I select Oct, I want one of the pyramids to show the count of only in Oct, whereas the other pyramid will show the count from Jan-Oct.

What will be the appropriate DAX to count monthly category?

```
Count: NMI =
CALCULATE( COUNT('Incident'[Case no.]), 'Incident'[Incident Class] = "NMI" ) + 0
```

[image]

At the moment, this is the DAX function I'm using to count one of the categories.

Right now, I'm only using the Filters to control it. For the monthly count, I will only select the current month. Whereas the YTD I will select on the Filter from Jan-Oct.

But when I select another month on the slicer, the pyramid on the current month will show blank as I only select for the current month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Date table linked to your `'Incident'` table, and that you are using this Date table for your slicer. Then you can have the following measures:

```
Count: NMI MTD = COALESCE( TOTALMTD([Count: NMI], 'Dim Date'[Date]), 0)
Count: NMI YTD = COALESCE( TOTALYTD([Count: NMI], 'Dim Date'[Date]), 0)
```

What I would suggest, is that you don't filter on `'Incident'[Case Class] = "NMI"` as you will then need to create the above for each of your Categories. Instead keep these category-less.

```
Count MTD = COALESCE( TOTALMTD(COUNT('Incident'[Case no.]), 'Dim Date'[Date]), 0)
Count YTD = COALESCE( TOTALYTD(COUNT('Incident'[Case no.]), 'Dim Date'[Date]), 0)
```

Then if you want for a particular category, simply add a filter or slicer with `'Incident'[Case Class]`. And if you wanted to target a particular category in a measure you can use:

```
Example Cat1 - Cat2 MTD =
  var cat 1 = [Count MTD]('Incident'[Case Class] = "Cat1")
  var cat 2 = [Count MTD]('Incident'[Case Class] = "Cat2")
  RETURN cat1 - cat2

// Note: [measure](filter) is shorthand for CALCULATE([measure], filter)
```